# Parsing XML Response using SOAP::Lite

Tags: xml, perl, xpath, soap, xml-parsing

Using [SOAP::Lite](https://metacpan.org/pod/SOAP::Lite) I'm trying to parse an XML Response; however, SOAP::SOM isn't giving me the desired values. It appears to take a different path than the one I'm trying to find.

```perl
    #!/usr/bin/env perl
    use strict;
    use warnings;
    use SOAP::Lite;
    use Data::Dumper;

    my $xml  = <<'__XML__';
    <S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
      <S:Body>
        <GetResponse>
          <services>
            <communication>
              <ruleset>
                <rule id="CD22222222">
                  <id>CD22222222</id>
                  <conditions>
                    <xtra>
                      <one id="sip:+22222222@ims">
                        <id>sip:+22222222@ims</id>
                      </one>
                      <one id="tel:+22222222">
                        <id>tel:+22222222</id>
                      </one>
                    </xtra>
                  </conditions>
                  <actions>
                    <allow>false</allow>
                  </actions>
                </rule>
                <rule id="CD33333333">
                  <id>CD33333333</id>
                  <conditions>
                    <xtra>
                      <one id="sip:+33333333@ims">
                        <id>sip:+33333333@ims</id>
                      </one>
                      <one id="tel:+33333333">
                        <id>tel:+33333333</id>
                      </one>
                    </xtra>
                  </conditions>
                  <actions>
                    <allow>false</allow>
                  </actions>
                </rule>
              </ruleset>
            </communication>
            <common-data>
              <subscription-list>
                <subscription id="PD11111111">
                  <id>PD11111111</id>
                  <number>11111111</number>
                  <key>alpha</key>
                  <default-subscription/>
                </subscription>
                <subscription id="CD22222222">
                  <id>CD22222222</id>
                  <number>22222222</number>
                  <key>beta</key>
                </subscription>
                <subscription id="CD33333333">
                  <id>CD33333333</id>
                  <number>33333333</number>
                  <key>gama</key>
                </subscription>
              </subscription-list>
            </common-data>
          </services>
        </GetResponse>
      </S:Body>
    </S:Envelope>
    __XML__

    my $som = SOAP::Deserializer->deserialize($xml);

    print Dumper($som->valueof('//services/common-data/subscription-list/'));
```

I'm getting the values for the same IDs, using a different XML path.

I'd like to get the `<key>` for the remaining IDs from the requested XML path, e.g. `beta` and `gamma`.

Comment: What do you mean by "the remaining IDs"?

Comment: I meant that I need to extract the `<key>` values of subscription IDs `CD22222222` and `CD33333333`. How do I get to the `<key>` or `<number>`?

Comment: I don't have a solution, but can confirm it seems to be merging the two node groups `communication` and `common-data` when decoding. I am seeing `actions`in the output for nodes 2 and 3. If I delete the `id` attributes from the `rule` nodes (or change their values to not match the later nodes), it works as you would expect.

Comment: Thank you @NickP- Yes, that's what I've observed. Sometimes I wonder if I should use `outputxml(1)` when calling `SOAP::Lite` and parse the XML using `XML::Twig`; however, I thought it'll become too complex with SOAP Faults and error handling.

Comment: @hq - And do you want to exclude info related to subscription ID `PD11111111`? If so, is the excluded ID always the first? Always starts with "PD" instead of "CD"? Generally, what is the common denominator of excluded in included IDs?

Comment: @JackFleeting Thanks for your message. I don't care for the extra values. I just need the `key` and `number` values, and would like to know which `number` is the `default-subscription`.

Comment: @hq - In your code, is `<number>11111111</number>` (or just `11111111`) the `default-subscription`?

Comment: @JackFleeting Just `11111111` and I'd like to know whether it's the `default-subscription`. I also would like to know the other numbers in the subscription-list, i.e. `22222222` and `33333333`.

Comment: @hq - To get both items, you will need two different xpath expressions; is that OK?

Comment: @JackFleeting sure, of course it's ok. I'm looking forward for your suggestion, thanks.

Comment: Sorry about the delay (didn't get your response, for some strange reason). See below.

Answer (score 1):

The xpath expression to get all date from the `<number>` element:

```
//services/common-data//subscription//number/text()
```

To get just the data from the `<number>` element which is inside a `<subscription-list>` which is a `<default-subscription/>` use:

```
//services/common-data//subscription[.//child::*[name()='default-subscription']]//number/text()
```

Comment: Would you kindly provide a working example to print the keys "alpha", "beta" and "gamma"? Thank you!